# nolearn auto add hidden layers

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, neural-network, nolearn

Trying to add more hidden layers to my neural network so I can compare the precision score of different layers using the same learn rates and momentum etc.

So I have the following:

```
from nolearn.dbn import DBN 
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split

from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

numFeat = 50 * 64 
labs = ["BC", "FL", "PRO1", "PRO2", "RP", "SD"]  # Defect types

hiddenAr = [numFeat, 6] # initial params for dbn
pos = len(hiddenAr) - 1

with open("all_defects.csv") as f:
reader = csv.reader(f)
for row in reader:
    input = [int(x) for x in row[:numFeat]]  
    labels += [labs.index(row[-1])]  # categorical labels in numerical form
    data += [input]

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
data, labels, test_size=0.25) 

for i in range (0, layer):
    hiddenAr.insert(pos, 300) # Add hidden layer

    dbn = DBN(
    hiddenAr,
    # Learning rate of algorithm
    learn_rates = 0.03,
    # Decay of learn rate
    learn_rate_decays=1,
    # Iterations of training data (epochs)
    epochs=10,
    # Verbosity level
    verbose=1,
    momentum= 0.03,
    use_re_lu=True
    )
```

What I have done there, is just added another 300 nodes to another hidden layer each time. However, it spits out a number of npmat.py errors when I add the layers to it for some reason.

Is there an obvious reason for this? I really would like to just automate it to add hidden layers itself so I can generate graphs and csv files for evaluation easily.

The errors happen after the hidden array has the second layer added to it, i.e. when i = 1 and then for each layer added after:

npmat.py:433: RuntimeWarning: inv
alid value encountered in add
  target.numpy_array[:] = vec.numpy_array + self.numpy_array

RuntimeWarning: inv
alid value encountered in less
  target.numpy_array[:] = self.numpy_array < val

RuntimeWarning: inv
alid value encountered in greater

npmat.py:969: RuntimeWarning: inv
alid value encountered in multiply

Data:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B12vhoNivII6My1GQ3E3T3JxQm8/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Could you add the entire code (e.g. import statements) and some data that allow to reproduce the errors? What errors do you receive?

Comment: @Cleb added in the errors and imports. To reproduce I would have to send you the csv file I am using I think. The problem is with the hiddenAr variable when I add in new layers I think. Everything is fine when I just have the nuerons hard coded in with [input, hidden, output] instead of hiddenAr being passed in.

Comment: Without data it is difficult to reproduce the problem. Maybe you can at least post a subset of the data?! And it would also be good to know which version of `nolearn` you use.

Comment: @Cleb I use version 0.5. Added in a link to the dataset on google drive and the other code before the section I was talking about.